# Login view not updating after user logs in?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have the following loginview code in my site.master design

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="Log.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
```

the log.aspx.cs file has the following code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Master.FindControl("CAMenu").Visible = false;
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUsername.Text == "admin" && txtPassword.Text == "1234")
        {
            Response.Redirect("NewEvent.aspx");
        }
    }
```

but the login view is not updating to Welcome "Username".. whats the mistake here. Should i change anything??? Please help

Comment: Have you tried debugging the log.aspx.cs page to see if the correct function is being called?

Comment: when the user clicks the login button the page redirects to the Newevent.aspx that has no problem. Thats why am not able to understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Login.Aspx i made the following changes..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Master.FindControl("CAMenu").Visible = false;
            Master.FindControl("loginStatus").Visible = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Logger().Log("ShortCom.Login.btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)", ex.Message);
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
    protected void LoadMessageBox(string MessageID)
    {
        try
        {
            messages = new GUIMessages();
            popupExtend = new ModalPopupExtender();
            lbMessage = (Label)Master.FindControl("label5");
            lbMessage.Text = messages.GetGUIMessage(GUIModule.Login, MessageID);
            popupExtend = (ModalPopupExtender)Master.FindControl("popupExtender");
            popupExtend.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Logger().Log("ShortCom.Login.LoadMessageBox(string MessageID)", ex.Message);
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string userName = txtUsername.Text;
            string password = txtPassword.Text;

            if (userName == string.Empty && password == string.Empty)
            {
                LoadMessageBox("5");
                txtUsername.Focus();


                return;
            }
            if (userName == string.Empty)
            {
                LoadMessageBox("1");
                txtUsername.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else if (password == string.Empty)
            {
                LoadMessageBox("3");

                txtPassword.Focus();
                return;
            }

            User user = new User(userName);
            DataTable tab = new DataTable();
            tab = user.GetUserDetails(userName);
            string firstName = string.Empty;
            string userPassword = string.Empty;
            string RoleID = string.Empty;
            string userID = string.Empty;
            Session["UserName"] = userName;
            if (tab.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                LoadMessageBox("6");
                txtPassword.Text = string.Empty;
                txtUsername.Text = string.Empty;
                txtUsername.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (tab.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                userID = tab.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                firstName = tab.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                userPassword = tab.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                RoleID = tab.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                Session["UserID"] = userID;
            }

                if (userPassword == password)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    LoadMessageBox("4");
                    txtPassword.Focus();
                    return;
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Logger().Log("ShortCom.Login.btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)", ex.Message);
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
```

And in Site.Master:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            if (Page.Title != "Login")
            {
                if (Session.Count == 0 || Session["Username"] == null)
                    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", true);
                CheckRole();

            }
            lblDateTime.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Logger().Log("ShortCom.SiteMaster.Page_Load()(object sender, EventArgs e)", ex.Message);
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
      }

    public void CheckRole()
    {
        try
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Count > 0)
            {
                string firstName = string.Empty;
                // string userPassword = string.Empty;
                string RoleID = string.Empty;
                Common common = new Common();
                DataTable tab = new DataTable();
                string userName = (string)Session["UserName"];
                User user = new User(userName);
                tab = user.GetUserDetails(userName);

                if (tab.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    firstName = tab.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    RoleID = tab.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                }

                if (RoleID != "1")
                {
                    int count = CAMenu.Items.Count;
                    if (count == 5)
                    {
                        for (int menuCount = 3; menuCount > 0; menuCount--)
                        {
                            string text = CAMenu.Items[menuCount - 1].Text;
                            CAMenu.Items.RemoveAt(menuCount - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    lbLoginMessage.Text = "Welcome," + " " + firstName;
                    loginStatus.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    lbLoginMessage.Text = "Welcome," + " " + firstName;
                    loginStatus.Visible = true;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Session.Abandon();
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Logger().Log("ShortCom.SiteMaster.CheckRole()", ex.Message);
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Apoorva... in your solution you are not at all using the <asp:LoginView> <asp:loginname> etc such type controls?

Comment: I dont remember.. This project was done almost a year back..!! sry

Comment: hmm.. i am also facing similar kind of problem... but no solution was obtained yet... :(

Answer (score 1):

Use login control onauthenticate event:

```
protected void OnAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
 if (txtUsername.Text == "admin" && txtPassword.Text == "1234")
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
        }
        else {
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }    

}
```

Comment: I shouldn't be using button click event?

Comment: my mistake was that i deleted the whole folder Account folder that u get as soon as we select asp.net web application from Visual Studio 2010 project types.

Comment: In your code, system doesn't know user is authenticated.  so you need to set cookie. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

Comment: when i take a new web application it will have all the things handled with in is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

Add this to your Log-in control Authenticate event handler... (***IN VB Please***)

```
If Membership.ValidateUser(login2.UserName, login2.Password) Then

            If Not Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl") Then

                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(login2.UserName, False)

            Else

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login2.UserName, False)
            End If

        Else
            Response.Write("Invalid UserID and Password")
        End If
```

The new control for posting the handling the event must have over-written the default event handling for the login control authentication event.
Hope it works.. Thanks.